# ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset results does not exist or is not supported?

Tags: arcpy, raster, error-000732

I'm trying to use

> MosaicToNewRaster

but a lot of errors are appears.
One of them is:

> ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset results does not exist or is not supported

My code is:

> import arcpy
>
> > from arcpy import env
> >     env.workspace = "C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\teste"
> >
> > arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management("SG-21-Z-D.tif;SG-22-Y-C.tif","C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS","marco.tif","","1_BIT","0.000833333353511989","1")

Should I change something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your workspace is missing the `r` before the path or you can replace one backslash `\` with two backslashes `\\` or you can replace the backslash `\` with a forward slash `/`. You can adjust your code based on the following example:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the current workspace
ws = env.workspace = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\DEM"

# Get a list of raster from the workspace
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
print(rasterlist)

# OR you can pass your target raster data to a list
# rasterlist = [SG-21-Z-D.tif,SG-22-Y-C.tif]

# Execute MosaicToNewRaster_management() tool
mosaic = arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasterlist,ws,'MosaicFinal.tif','',pixel_type='16_BIT_SIGNED',number_of_bands=1)
```

Check the [Mosaic To New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) help for more information.